# Call a different variable in each loop depending on a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a for loop, in which I want to call a different pd.Dataframes in each loop and add a certain column ('feedin') to another dataframe. The variable name consists of 'feedin_' + x. Lets say a,b and c. So in the first loop I want to call the variable feedin_a and add the column 'feedin' to the new dataframe. In the next feedin_b and so on.

I pass a list of ['a', 'b', 'c'] and try to combine feedin_+ a. But since the list consists of string parameters it wont call the variable

```py
feedin_a = pd.Dataframe
feedin_b = pd.Dataframe
feedin_c = pd.Dataframe

list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for name in list:

df.new['feedin_'+name] = 'feedin_'+name['feedin']
```

Which doesnt work because the variable is called as a string. I hope you get my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: well the dictionary would work, but as you can see I need the 'a' one time as a string to call the new column and one time to call the variable

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons it's not a great idea to use variables `feedin_a`, `feedin_b`, when you really need a data structure like a list.

If you can't change this, you can looking up the names in the `locals()` (or `globals()` dictionary:

```
df.new['feedin_'+name] = locals()['feedin_'+name]['feedin']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use locals() so it should be something like that:

```
feedin_a = pd.Dataframe
feedin_b = pd.Dataframe
feedin_c = pd.Dataframe

name_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for name in list:
    key = 'feedin_{}'.format(name)
    df.new[key] = locals()[key]
```

also check this [Python, using two variables in getattr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516778/python-using-two-variables-in-getattr)

p.s. do not use `list` as variable name because it is built-in python object

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your exact question by using `locals()`.  In the comments someone pointed out another way to achieve the thing you're after: using a dictionary to hold your "variable names" as string that can be looked up with string manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd

dataframes = dict()

letter_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for letter in letter_list:
    dataframes['feedin_'+letter] = pd.DataFrame()

for name in letter_list:
    dataframes['feedin_'+name].insert(0, 'feedin_'+name, None)

print(dataframes)
```

> ```
> {'feedin_a': Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [feedin_a]
> Index: [], 'feedin_b': Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [feedin_b]
> Index: [], 'feedin_c': Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [feedin_c]
> Index: []}
> ```

If you intend to do a lot of calling your DataFrames by string manipulation, this is a good way to go.